Questions about Toast UI Grid
First of all, I ask for your understanding that I am not good at English.
I use Toast Ui Grid
if grid cell click => i want get first cell.value
The cell is configured like this.
|board_no|board_title|user|


if click board_title -> i want get board_no number
i use for formatter, then i get board_no and i use 
formatter: function (e) {
  return `<a href="detail?no=${e.value}">${e.value}</a>`;  
},

how can i get board_no, when i click board_title?
thanks for your help

grid.on("click", function (ev) {
    let board = grid.getRow(ev.rowKey);
    location.href = "/detail?no=" + board.board_no;
});

find rowKey method and this is my answer
i finished
